# What is returned by the post mates tracking_url when the Creaete Delivery API is called

Tags: postmates

I am looking into integrating with the Postmates API. Their documentation lists states that the Create a Delivery API returns a tracking url:

> tracking_url: This url can be used to track the courier during the
>   delivery

However, this does not mention what is returned. Is it the latitude and longitude? Is it an image?

What is actually returned by this URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a web page with delivery status and a map. You can create a delivery using your sandbox key and check it out.
If you want to get updates for the delivery you either need to setup a web-hook or pull delivery details using get delivery API.